# Direct download link for public file SharePoint

Tags: document-library, url, download

I'm looking for a way to let users download a file directly, without having to click the "Open" button.

`https://veodin2.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/Sales/EZdR8fpZ66NNqPvMdgN0gNYBXfi5vCRhMeKoPnkKuGJ4PQ?e=SFw9sv`

It seems like other answers are not about public files / SharePoint Document Libraries only "Personal".

Comment: Did you find any way to resolve **Direct download link for public file SharePoint**
if yes please let me know. I am facing the same issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original path:

```
https://veodin2.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/Sales/EZdR8fpZ66NNqPvMdgN0gNYBXfi5vCRhMeKoPnkKuGJ4PQ?e=SFw9sv
```

Replaced with download:

```
https://veodin2.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/Sales/EZdR8fpZ66NNqPvMdgN0gNYBXfi5vCRhMeKoPnkKuGJ4PQ?download=1
```

I replaced everything after the last `?` with `download=1`. Then the link can be used in my code to pull the file down.

**Note**: This will work for `.doc`, `.xlsx` & `.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Change your link directly to the file in the library:

`https://veodin2.sharepoint.com/Sales/Shared%20Documents/SlideProof%2FVeodinSlideProof_Setup_v4.msi`

Comment: This will work for authorized user, but not anonymous

Comment: This would be more useful if you tell how you changed the URL in the question to become this URL. That URL is full of scrambled characters and yours is actual english words and slashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you append `&download=1` to the end it will redirect you to the direct link.

Your link would become:

`https://veodin2.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/Sales/EZdR8fpZ66NNqPvMdgN0gNYBXfi5vCRhMeKoPnkKuGJ4PQ?e=SFw9sv&download=1`